# HTML5/JavaScript bandwidth speed test for mobile app

Tags: javascript, html, testing, mobile

I am struggling with one problem since a couple of days.

I am developing a mobile app in HTML5. My client wants to add a Bandwidth Speed Test option on it.

So I started looking around on the web, what was done, I found out that almost everything its done using ADOBE FLASH ... wont work... it needs to be Javascript/HTML5.

I found this:

https://github.com/nesk/network.js/issues/64

I tried to use it but ... I receive an error during the download test:

(console output of the example page)

- [Download] Restarting measures with 10.000 MB of data
- [Download] The
  minimum delay of 8.000 seconds has not been reached
- [Download]
  Restarting measures with 10.000 MB of data...
- [Download] Final average speed: **NaN MBps** [Download] Finished measures

I sincerily dont know what the problem is, I tried to debug the code but I could not get with the reason of this NaN (Not a Number) Error.

Any Help?
Suggestions?
Other solutions?

Remember I am developing a mobile solution (html5)

Comment: have you looked at https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com/

Comment: Its not what I am talking about, but thanks for you time my friend.

What I need to do is something like this on my mobile app:

http://beta.speedtest.net/

Comment: sorry, I thought that you meant to want to add a speed test for websites. Why don't you copy the code from speedtest.net? It's html5

Comment: I tried to , I dont know how to get ... at least ... the same "speedometer" embeeded in my website without all the Ads, etc.

Answer (score -2):

that mean your network problem or host problem

```
[Download] Restarting measures with 10.000 MB of data
[Download] The minimum delay of 8.000 seconds has not been reached
[Download] Restarting measures with 10.000 MB of data...
[Download] Final average speed: NaN MBps [Download] Finished measures
```

this mean your site speed low for used speedtest like speedtest.net. they used multiple layer network. try used raspaberry pi concept that you can make fast for small multilayer network